# Can I claim for my whole group's tickets on Delay Repay with Great Western Railway?

Tags: uk, trains, refunds, delays

My Great Western Railways train (GWR) was delayed by 45 minutes, and an announcement was made that 'Delay Repay' claims would be permitted.

I understand that I can submit my tickets through the [GWR website](https://delayrepay.gwr.com/) for a partial refund. I was part of a group of four travellers (including two children) and had paid for all the rail tickets myself. Can I claim for all the tickets as one claim?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, according to [GWR's Delay Repay FAQs](https://www.gwr.com/help-and-support/refunds-and-compensation/delay-repay).

> I travelled with a group, do I need to claim for each ticket separately?
>
> We know that it’s not always possible, or practical, to claim individually. For example, when you’ve travelled with children. Our online form lets you submit a claim for multiple passengers in one go.
>
> Just upload a copy of all the tickets you are claiming for and let us know how much each of them cost.

Comment: In December I bought two return tickets, one each for myself and partner, and the GWR train from Bristol Temple Meads to Cardiff Central was stopped just before the Severn Tunnel (there was a broken-down train in the tunnel) and sent back to Bristol eventually. I made one Delay Repay, attaching a scan of both tickets. It was rejected as the tickets had not been cut in two. I resubmitted and got the whole payment back.